# WP7: What is the easiest way to play a system sound in XNA

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, playback, audio

I just need to play some simple sounds like a simple "click" in my XNA game. What is the easiest way to do that. And any way I can find the sound file from system? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to add some sound effects to your XNA game. To do that it seems like all you need is to add it to the content pipeline. I found a couple of samples here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195053.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203895(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx